# why 'n = 5 is the valid syntax?[Scala]

Tags: scala, syntax, literals

```
object solution extends App {
  'n = 5
}
```

It gives the compile time **Error: value update is not a member of object Symbol
println('n = 'n)** which is understandable. Because literals are the fixed values in the source code. But what is the reason the above syntax is valid?

Comment: If I try to compile it without the surrounding `object`, the IntelliJ IDE worksheet gives a different error: `identifier expected but symbol literal found`

Comment: that error is more specific then this one but don't you think this should not be valid syntax? @jwvh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the syntax is valid is … well … because it is:

```
implicit class UpdateableSymbol(val s: Symbol.type) extends AnyVal {
  def update[A](s: String, v: A) = println(s"`Symbol.update` called with s = $s and v = $v")
}

'n = 5
// `Symbol.update` called with s = n and v = 5
```

As you can see, there is absolutely nothing wrong with the syntax, so why should it be invalid? The error message tells you what the problem is: you are calling `Symbol.update` but that doesn't exist. A missing method is not a syntactic error, it is a semantic error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_92).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> reify('n)
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[Symbol] = Expr[Symbol](Symbol.apply("n"))

scala> val a = 'n
a: Symbol = 'n

scala> a = 5
<console>:15: error: reassignment to val
       a = 5
         ^

scala> a.update(5)
<console>:16: error: value update is not a member of Symbol
       a.update(5)
         ^
```

Desugar it, and you will find the answer.

In Scala, operators are methods.

For Symbol, see https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Symbol.scala

Comment: I am not asking why it is giving me the compile time error, I am asking why this syntax is even valid? That i understand why it is giving me the error.

Comment: Operators are methods. I've updated my answer just now.

Comment: @RamanMishra  It is a good idea that the compiler finds bugs in compile time.

Comment: Operators are methods ' (literal operator) calls the constructor of the Symbol class and creates a symbol, I am still not getting the point of reassigning value for a literal according to me that should not be the valid syntax.

Comment: The reason this is valid syntax is that it is syntactic sugar for `Symbol.update("n", 5)`, which is perfectly legal, valid, sensible syntax. The parser doesn't know, doesn't care, and *shouldn't* care whether a method call is legal or not, it should only care whether syntax is legal or not. Which it is.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: The error message the OP posted says that there is no method `update` on `object Symbol`, so it is definitely trying to call `Symbol.update` (i.e. the `update` method on the `Symbol` *object*), not `'n.update` or `Symbol("n").update` (both of which would be the `update` method of the `Symbol` *class*). See my answer which demonstrates that an `update` method with 2 parameters is called.